# How to Ignore Properties in IdentityUser during json serialization

Tags: json, asp.net-core-3.1

How can I ignore some properties during json serialization in asp.net core 3.1, I can do in other model like

```
       public class AppUser : IdentityUser<string>
    {
[JsonIgnore]
        public bool Activated { get; set; }
        public int? PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

But how on identity properties like `passwordHash`,`securityStamp` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I figure out on what to do

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<string>
    {
[JsonIgnore]
        public bool Activated { get; set; }
        public int? PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore]
        public override string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

I Found some idea here [link](https://gist.github.com/theuntitled/7c70fff994993d7644f12d5bb0dc205f)